# How to get IP Address in request?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I'm trying to get IP Address on Asp.net core API.

My system looks like this:

```
request(10.10.10.108) --> firewall (10.10.10.1) --> application
```

I used this code but it return 10.10.10.1, which is the IP of the firewall:

```
var ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddess;
```

How can I get the IP of request the client (10.10.10.108) in my application?

Comment: You need to configure forwarded headers middleware.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 3):

Check for the request header "X-Forwarded-For"

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]
```

If this is populated it will likely contain the real origin of the request.